# GNU split (UNIX command) creating files not matching pattern after reaching "z"

Tags: shell, unix, split, gnu-coreutils

So  I was spliting some large files, everything worked properly until a file of 81GB came to scene. The split command seems that made its job, but the last files has a non correlated name. Look at the right bottom of picture.

[image]

And I'm using the command like this:

```
split -b 125M ./2014.txt 2014/2014_
```

Anyone knows why instead of create the file `2014_za` created the `2014_zaaa`?

Comment: `split` is not actually part of bash. It's perfectly capable of being installed on machines that don't have bash at all. You could invoke it from  Python, C, or any other language; it's not shipped with the shell, included in its source code, or a bash component in any other meaningful way.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Hackerman Yes, I 'll try. The question is: why it creates a `_zaaa` file instead of the corresponding `_za`?

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres because if it created _za and _zb , the pieces would no longer be in order when sorted alphabetically. You would no longer be able to do `cat 2014_*` to re-join it. GNU split is smart and reserves _z* for longer prefixes

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I couldn't either with a file less than 80Gb. I'm running ubuntu 14.04. And split is the one packed in GNU coreutils 8.21

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres, ...not even if you set `-b` to tell it to create files of, say, 5 or 10 bytes each? Thank you for the version number -- that helps.

Comment: @thatotherguy that seems to be the correct answer

Comment: (The BSD implementation, by the way, fails with a nonzero exit status and the error "too many files" when it overruns `_zz`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for editing the answer, it's much better now

Comment: @CharlesDuffy interesting fact. Thank you all for solving this

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres, ...to be fair, the test scenario I ran was with input from a pipeline, thus preventing it from detecting the amount of content up-front. It might possibly behave better with input from a file, where it could use the `stat()` call to detect its size. (This is one reason why `bar < foo` is better replaced with `cat foo | bar`: the former provides a direct, `stat`able file handle).

Comment: There is a bug report that explains this split behavior :https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25832

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have 676 files named `[a-z][a-z]`, while your command required more.

Here are some options for what `split` could do:

1. Crash.

   This is the behavior mandated by POSIX, and followed by macOS.
2. Start writing larger suffixes.

   This is a bad choice because after `_zz` comes `_aaa`, but now the files will show up in the wrong order in `ls` and `cat *` will no longer join them in correct order.
3. Save the last range, `_z`, for longer suffixes.

   This is a good choice because after `_yz` comes `_zaaa`, which has room to grow while still remaining in alphabetical order. This is what GNU does, and the behavior you're seeing.

If you want all the names to be uniform without triggering any of these behaviors, just use a larger suffix length with `-a 6` to ensure you have enough room.

Comment: I had a similar issue using numeric suffixes (jumped from 89 to 9000). Thanks for explaining this, it makes sense.